# Coupling vs Association in java

Tags: java, oop, associations, coupling

*Coupling* refers to the extent of knowledge one class knows about another class, or it  refers to the degree of direct knowledge that one element has of another.

*Association* is a relation between two separate classes which establishes through their Objects.

I read many sites about these concepts, but I do not understand exactly the difference between the two. Please explain for me the difference between Coupling  and Association. Can I say Coupling is the relation to a class and Association is the relation to an object?

References

- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/association-composition-aggregation-java/
- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/coupling-in-java/
- https://www.edureka.co/blog/coupling-in-java/

Comment: Please add links to the sites where you read about these concepts.

Comment: @jaco0646   https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/association-composition-aggregation-java/  and https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/coupling-in-java/   , 
 https://www.edureka.co/blog/coupling-in-java/   etc. I searched google and read many sites which  to show!  I knew these concept are different but not  understand their really  differences